# How to load file using Cornerstone Dicom viewer?

Tags: dicom

I need to show dicom images, which will be just a dicom file (dcm) available via a URL. I currently using *Cornerstone* DICOM viewer. I understand that I need to have an image loader, but I'm confused about whether to use the WADO image loader or the web image loader. I'm won't know if the DICOM file are "P10" or not. What image loader is best if I just have a link to a `.dcm` file and want to load that into *Cornerstone*?

#### Update

It appears that the `cornestoneWADOImageLoader` will load files just fine. All you have to do it prepend `wadouri:` to the url and pass to the `loadImage` function of cornerstone (assuming you setup the image loader).

Answer (score 3):

If it's a valid DICOM image, then it's a Part 10 image:

https://github.com/chafey/cornerstoneFileImageLoader

As Kritzel notes, WADO and web image are different formats.

Answer (score 1):

cornestoneWADOImageLoader will load the files with .dcm in url ,all you need to pass the url path to the cornestoneWADOImageLoader.here is example code of it .For Run this project ,you need to have the cornerstone core and dicom parser as well

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import cornerstone from "cornerstone-core";
import dicomParser from "dicom-parser";
import * as cornerstoneWADOImageLoader from "cornerstone-wado-image-loader";

cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.external.cornerstone = cornerstone;

cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.external.dicomParser = dicomParser;

const Viewer = () => {
  const [a, setA] = useState(0);
  const divRef = useRef();
  const cvsRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    divRef.current = document.createElement("div");
    divRef.current.style.width = 500;
    divRef.current.style.height = 500;
    console.log(divRef.current);
    cornerstone.enable(divRef.current);
    cvsRef.current = divRef.current.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
    cvsRef.current.width = 500;
    cvsRef.current.height = 500;
    cvsRef.current.style.width = "500px";
    cvsRef.current.style.height = "500px";
    cornerstone
      .loadImage(
        "wadouri:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstoneWADOImageLoader/master/testImages/CT2_J2KR"
      )
      .then(image => {
        console.log(image);

        cornerstone.displayImage(divRef.current, image);

        const viewport = {
          invert: false,
          pixelReplication: false,
          voi: {
            windowWidth: 400,
            windowCenter: 200
          },
          scale: 1,
          translation: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
          }
          // colormap: "hot"
        };

        cornerstone.setViewport(divRef.current, viewport);
        cornerstone.updateImage(divRef.current);
        console.log(
          cvsRef.current.getContext("2d").getImageData(250, 250, 10, 10)
        );
        setA(2);
      });
  }, []);

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(
      cvsRef.current &&
        cvsRef.current.getContext("2d").getImageData(250, 250, 10, 10)
    );
  }, 1000);

  return (
    (divRef.current && (
      <div
        ref={node => {
          node.appendChild(divRef.current);
        }}
      />
    )) ||
    null
  );
};

export default Viewer;
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see:

- WADO image loader will not work, because the image is "just a DICOM file available via URL". WADO however, is a more complex protocol. So this would fail on the server side
- Web image loader will not work, because it only supports "web images" - PNG and JPEG